# Cronjob on Ubuntu not executing php script

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I am trying to set up cronjobs to excecute some emailing to clients periodically but I am seeing no output from the test I wrote here is the crontab line

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/pms/notices/test.php
```

and here is the test.php code

```
<?php
 include(__DIR__ . "/config.php");
 $log_message = 'It works';
    error_log($log_message . "On:" . date("l jS \of F, Y, h:i:s A P") . "\n", 3, ROOT_PATH .'Logs/activity.log');      
<?
```

I expect the activity.log file to have 'it works' written to it every minute but nothing is. Could I be doing anything wrong? If yes what is it? or where can I get good tutorial on how to set up cronjobs I have tried changing my line to

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/pms/notices/test.php
```

as suggested in the answer to an almost similar question but that has not helped

Comment: Please share the output of this command

"/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/pms/notices/test.php"

Are there any errors thrown?
Also share your config.php and ROOT_PATH value.

Comment: Its is just not showing anything actually working when I run the command manually but cron jobs that I have created to run it automatically does nothing